# Problem with permalink structure for Wordpress custom post_type archive template

Tags: templates, archives, post-type

I have looked at other similar answers to this question but not finding my way.
I am using Custom Post Types plugin for a custom post_type called 'product' and has_archive is set to 'true' in the settings
I am using an archive template called archive-product.php
The archive template is used and works as long as the permalink structure is default. However, I want it to be the postname permalink structure. If I change it to this in permalinks then the page for products uses the standard loop (maybe archive template or index loop)
What is the fix for this? I have seen some posts talk about an issue with flush_rewrite_rules() ? but this is implemented anyway when you save the permalink page so how can that be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use rewrite parameter in register_post_type
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'product','with_front' => FALSE) and change the permalink structure to postname.